# Wordpress media upload memory size problem

Tags: mysql, wordpress, upload

I have a problem with upload files to wordpress system.
If i tried to upload a test.jpg file with size of arround 80 KB, than i get the follow error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8388616 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/*****/httpdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1890
```

I have tried to put follow code in wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT' , '512M' );
```

But without success.

On the server log after uploaded the test file I get this error:

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/*****/httpdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1889\n', referer: https://*********/wp-admin/media-new.php
```

---

Now i have put an other backup so I got an other error:

```
WordPress databasefout: [Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY']
INSERT INTO `x9i8Z_icl_translations` (`element_type`, `language_code`, `trid`) VALUES ('post_attachment', 'nl', '7526')


Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/***********/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/classes/media/duplication/class-wpml-media-attachments-duplication.php on line 201

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/***********/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/classes/media/duplication/class-wpml-media-attachments-duplication.php on line 201
0
```

Its strange because on the old version it works good, but if i put all the database data on a new schema it doesnt work any more :(

Comment: have you installed any plugin recently ?

Comment: @user2584538 I have remove an old version to the new one, but i copied the whole website file and database. But i got some other errors and now i'm fixxing all the other error.

Comment: Try deactivating all plugins. Then activate one by one while testing the upload. It seems something wrong with a plugin.

Comment: You're asking two very different and distinct questions.  If you're having server allocation issues, change your settings using WHM or similar.  If you don't have access to server admin tools, you can (possibly - depending on your host) change them using a custom php.ini.  Your second question should be its own thread, as it is an unrelated issue to the first question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup `upload_max_size` via `wp-config.php` file.

@ini_set`( 'upload_max_size' , '512M' );`

It is better to increase the max execution time with the upload size. So, your final output will look like this.

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '512M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '512M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '2400' );
```

Comment: I put the code in wp-config.php but without success :(

Comment: @Gurdt Try deactivating all plugins. Then activate one by one while testing the upload. It seems something wrong with a plugin.

Comment: Allready done but if i dissable "WPML Multilingual CMS" than i can't upload anything than he stucks on upload 100% and shows no error. And if i disable the plugin the media libary is empty

Comment: Then it is better to ask "WPML Multilingual CMS" support

Comment: Trying to modify PHP configuration settings through the WordPress config is probably the least effective way to do that.  If OP has access to WHM or other backend server admin tools, they should be using those. As a secondary option, those settings would be better set in a custom php.ini.  OP's second question has nothing to do with server allocations.

Comment: @JustinR. Agree with you. This is the simplest way to fix it. Otherwise need to do it via `.htaccess` or `php.ini`